# Resttemplate - request the pojo itself or request the json string and parse it

Tags: java, json, rest

I got two options:

Requesting the object

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class);
```

or requesting the JSON

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

and parse it afterwards.

Behind the scenes both will be using JSON, but is there any convention or best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create java object for corresponding json then response will be serialized automatically:

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, MyResponseBean.class);
```

For java bean generation [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) is usefull.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I did as well :) just wanted to know if there is some kind of convention or something. Thank you tho bud! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's at least two reasons to prefer `RestTemplate` unmarshalling your object for you rather than first retrieving a `String`:

1. it's likely more memory-efficient; but much more importantly
2. it leads to cleaner code!

If you retrieve a `String` directly, you have to first read that whole result into memory, and *then* parse this into your object model. The message converters in `RestTemplate` have an opportunity to read this into your object model byte-by-byte from the response `InputStream`. Granted, they may not be able to build an object graph without loading the whole response into memory anyway, but at least this way you don't have to do it twice.

But more importantly... why would you do this yourself, when Spring has battle-hardened, infinitely configurable code to do this for you?

Say that, every time you get a JSON response from RestTemplate, you deal with it yourself with:

`MyThing thing = objectMapper.readValue(stringResult, MyThing.class);`

...isn't even that one line worth saving? Coupled with this, I'd argue that JSON umarshalling is inherently a cross-cutting concern that makes sense to be configured centrally.