# How do I ignore the root node when reading in a json rest api?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I am reading in a rest api that returns a **Json** file. I need to ignore the "result" and "optionChain" nodes. I am using **Spring Boot** with **Jackson** to deal with the mapping of objects.

Thanks in Advance!

For the Json File [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UU7g4yAottQ9jioj50uVzR7n_lMyhoq9/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my Main:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Collections;

@SpringBootApplication
public class OptionsImpliedMovementApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OptionsImpliedMovementApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        String resourceURL = url;
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(resourceURL, HttpMethod.GET,entity, String.class);

        String rawJson = response.getBody();


        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //need to read in json ignoring root node



    }
```

Comment: So basically you want to ignore the entire JSON?

Comment: No the problem is that when I try to map the JSON objects to java objects, it thinks that result is an array. I just need to read in the information after the result node.

Comment: After or inside ?
"result" is in fact an array. Why don't you simply change your JSON document?

Comment: Anyway I'm at the gym now, I'll give you a snippet later.

Comment: Yes I would like to read inside "result". But I do not want to change the JSON document because every time I make a request to rest api, I will continue to receive this style of JSON document. So Im trying to find a way to only read whats inside the result. Since the "result" is an array with only one insert, I feel like its pointless to create a result array and instead read only whats inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already getting JSON response , then would recommend to use

```
restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, MyPOJO.class);
```

instead of `String.class` define your own POJO based on JSON response coming as you have attached in file.json.

In a handy way you can generate your POJO against your JSON from : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ quickly and easily.

So it should look like :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"optionChain"
})
public class MyPOJO {

@JsonProperty("optionChain")
private OptionChain optionChain;
// getters and setters 
}
```

And another one :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"result",
"error"
})
public class OptionChain {

@JsonProperty("result")
private List<Result> result = null;
@JsonProperty("error")
private Object error;
// getter and setters

}
```

And other like :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"expirationDate",
"hasMiniOptions",
"calls",
"puts"
})
public class Option {

@JsonProperty("expirationDate")
private Integer expirationDate;
@JsonProperty("hasMiniOptions")
private Boolean hasMiniOptions;
@JsonProperty("calls")
private List<Call> calls = null;
@JsonProperty("puts")
private List<Put> puts = null;
```

So once you'll have the response as :

```
ResponseEntity<MyPOJO> response = restTemplate.exchange(resourceURL, HttpMethod.GET,entity, MyPOJO.class);
```

Then response.getBody will give the content inside optionChain node which is what you're looking for. You can then normally drill down to whatever node you want as now you have everything in plain java objects and you can ignore whatever you want or use whatever is needed.

Using objectMapper also you can then achieve the same :

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     MyPojo myPojo=  mapper.readValue(rawJson, MyPojo.class);
```

Comment: ha ha, lot of for nothing ! Reminds me of the 'memory efficient' discussion why unmarshalling your object right away rather than first retrieving a String. Would recommend to think again !

Comment: Thank you! All this code actually helps me build custom methods. The jsonschema2pojo reduces the time to have to type out the code.

Comment: Yes @LppEdd I would have to convert the remaining JSON that your solution would return the same way as this. But both provided a working solution so thank you to both!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342423/resttemplate-request-the-pojo-itself-or-request-the-json-string-and-parse-it
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271663/use-json-objects-or-pojos-in-back-end-service
anyway I'll let the user to decide

Comment: Having multiple classes to obtain a single one as output is inefficient (Jackson does a lot of objects instantiations in the background) and unneeded. The less the number of classes you have around, the better it is. Centralizing the JSON transformation, that's what's important.

Comment: does the number of classes is what botherin you? Then would recommend to read https://hackernoon.com/solid-principles-made-easy-67b1246bcdf , Please see here its not one time activity what we are having is a connection, data is being requested from another resource and just imagine (keeping memory in mind) everytime you get everything as String and then retrieve...remember what it takes to be a String!  And I strictly dis-agree to : "The less the number of classes you have around, the better it is".  Looks like your personal opinion.

Comment: @VibrantVivek SOLID doesn't matter here. Start bloating your project with POJOs and you'll never go back. I worked on big projects, especially on EJB containers, where POJOs were 90 percent of the objects around.  Too many classes are a recipe for ruining a project and how well it's understood. I'm not really worried about heap consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Quick (performant) and working.

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(rawJson);
final JsonNode result = jsonNode.get("optionChain")
                                .get("result");

final JsonNode firstResult = result.get(0);
final YourResultClass resultObject = objectMapper.treeToValue(firstResult, YourResultClass.class);
```

If you need to ignore unknown fields

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = 
      new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```